# Enforce an expired license ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using [Portable.Licensing](https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing) in my ASP.NET Web API application.  I am using a daily background task started in `Startup.cs` that checks a license file and public key using `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`.  If the license is not validated after the check, I want to make the application stops working until an updated license file installed.

By "stop working" I mean Web API requests should not go through or the whole Web API application should be stopped or unloaded.  The license has expired, they shouldn't be able to use the application.

The license checking part I've explained works but I can't find a way to make the application stop working while the application is already running.  I've tried this but requests still seem to work

```
AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
```

An easy way would be to put the license check in each http request method or in a filter and return an error but I want to avoid that.  That `IO file read` is being done each time it checks the license and I think this can cause performance issues.

Are there any ways to accomplish this?

Comment: can you load it into the session the first time and then read it from there in your filter, to avoid disk I/O?

Comment: @ADyson I will look into that and it might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Global.asax.cs` `Application_Start` I loaded the values like this

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.Lock();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["licenseExp"] = licenseManager.ExpirationDate;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.UnLock();
```

Then I created an `ActionFilterAttribute` (using Web API) which is called on every http request.  In the ActionFilter

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {

        DateTime licenseExp = DateTime.Parse(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["licenseExp"].ToString());            
        if (DateTime.Compare(licenseExp, DateTime.UtcNow) < 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Your license has expired.");
        }            
    }
```

This enforces the expiration date in the license and will not need to do an IO license read each request.  The comment by @ADyson contributed the most to finding this solution but No Refunds No Returns contributed too.

Answer (score 1):

We have instrumentation that wraps every request through our WebAPI app.  We install it once at startup like this:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new InstrumentAllCallsHandler());
```

In your .ctor you could load your file and store the expiration date.  In the handler all you have to do is check the current date and respond by forwarding the request through the pipeline or whatever you want to do if the expiration date has passed.